# How different instruction types are defined in AMD microprocessors to identify DirectPath vs VectorPath flows?

Tags: cpu, 64-bit, cpu-architecture, prefetch, opteron

In AMD 10h architecture like Opteron the prefetched instructions after being aligned are separated into 2 flows: DirectPath (or Fastpath) and VectorPath (Microcode engine).  Later these flows are ready for integer or floating-point execution paths.

What is the method the fetched instructions are marked for either flow?  Is there a flag bit or some sort?

The AMD documentation is very vague about the differentiation mechanizm.  The only mentioned is:

When the target 32-byte instruction window is
obtained from the L1 instruction cache, **the instruction bytes are examined** to determine whether the
type of basic decode to take place is DirectPath or VectorPath.

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR: the different paths aren't really that different.  The bigger difference after decoding is FP/SIMD vs. Integer, which go in different schedulers, even though there are DirectPath instructions for both.

See also [David Kanter's Barcelona (AMD Fam10h) microarchitecture write-up](https://www.realworldtech.com/barcelona/3/).  His diagram of the front-end in K10/K8/Core2 is highly relevant:

[image: enter link description here]

For more links to stuff like this, see the [x86 tag wiki on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

---

From Agner Fog's microarch guide (http://agner.org/optimize/), K8/K10 chapter:

> **17.3 Predecoding and instruction length decoding**
>
> An instruction can have any length from 1 to 15 bytes. The instruction boundaries are
>   marked in the code cache and copied into the level-2 cache. Instruction length decoding is
>   therefore rarely a bottleneck, **even though the instruction length decoder can handle only
>   one instruction per clock cycle**.

This might be separate from generating the other pre-decode info, since Agner says instruction-length info is stored in L2 cache as well, but other pre-decode info has to be regenerated when fetching from L2 into L1I.

> The level-1 code cache contains a considerable amount of predecode information. This
>   includes information about where each instruction ends, where the opcode byte is, as well
>   as **distinctions between single, double and vector path instructions** and identification of
>   jumps and calls. Some of this information is copied to the level-2 cache, but not all. The low
>   bandwidth for instructions coming from the level-2 cache may be due to the process of
>   adding more predecode information.

The actual details of the storage format for the extra data isn't known.  Presumably each line of L1I cache has some extra bytes in the data array beyond the 64B of memory contents, in some custom format.  It seems like that would take significant extra space to handle the corner case where every instruction was a single byte.

---

These separate flows aren't really all *that* separate.  There are three decoders, and they can either decode up-to-3 DirectPath instructions (producing up-to-three macro-ops), or one VectorPath instruction can be decoded.

Agner Fog says:

> Vector path instructions are less efficient than single or double
>   instructions because they require exclusive access to the decoders and
>   pipelines and do not always reorder optimally. For example:
>
> ```
> ; Example 17.1. AMD instruction breakdown
> xchg eax, ebx        ; Vector path, 3 ops
> nop                  ; Direct path, 1 op
> xchg ecx, edx        ; Vector path, 3 ops
> nop                  ; Direct path, 1 op
> ```
>
> This sequence takes 4 clock cycles to decode because the vector path
>   instructions must decode alone.

(That example is for K8.  K10 runs `xchg r,r` as a 2 m-op instruction.  Agner says only K8 has DirectPath Double instructions (and K10 only has single vs. vector), but that doesn't agree with what David Kanter's diagram shows.  It shows a pack buffer with a throughput of 3 m-ops (aka uops) per clock, but the decoders feeding into it can produce 1 or 2 uops each per cycle.

Bulldozer family has double-instructions too, and its decoders can produce up to 4 m-ops per clock.  So it can decode a single Vectorpath instruction, or 1-1-1-1 (four Directpath single instructions), or 2-1-1.  This implies that only the first decoder can handle Double instructions. 
 Piledriver and later can also decode 2-2 patterns (two consecutive DirectPath Double instructions).

Ryzen has a uop cache for decoded instructions.  It can issue up to 5 DirectPath Single instructions per clock into its out-of-order core.  But if any of the instructions are Double instructions, it can run 6 uops per clock.  (So AVX / AVX2 can be worth it on Ryzen even though it runs 256b instructions as two uops.)

---

**Intel's strategy is quite different**:

They pre-decode length, but don't store it anywhere long-term.  The decoders try decoding, and if an instruction doesn't work in a simple decoder, it's a multi-uop instruction and will have to wait for the next clock cycle for the complex decoder to handle it.

The complex decoder can handle instructions up to 4 uops directly, otherwise the uops have to come from microcode.